# Image is flickering continuously in pressing button?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-animation

The Image is flickering as I continuously push the button. The problem might be in `ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,500)` . How can I resolve the problem?

I am trying to animate in HTML 5 canvas.
I need a moving object in canvas and when I push the button, the other moving object follow the previous without flickering.

```
function draw(x,y){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,500); // This may be the problem
    var img=document.getElementById("Image");
    ctx.drawImage(img,50,y);
    ctx.restore();
    y -= 10;
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',50);
}
```

HTML 5

```
<button onclick="draw(0,500)">Draw</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="500">
</canvas>
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting this flicker in Chrome. Which browser do you have problems with?

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle, so we can see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem may be because you aren't clearing the entire `canvas`. Try this:

```
function draw(x,y){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var img=document.getElementById("Image");
    ctx.drawImage(img,50,y);
    ctx.restore();
    y -= 10;
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',50);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhXCq/)

Answer (score 0):

The image flicker when you press the button more than once, which means you start the setTimeout() more than once. Add a variable to check if it's already been pressed.